# CustomConverter do not get applied for ReactiveMongoTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

Hello Spring community,

I have a Spring Boot 3 application with a Mongo DB. I use Spring data mongo reactive to communicate with the database and that works great apart from this issue.

I have a property that Id like to capsulate with another class but I need the same database structure for compatibility.

```
@Data
@Builder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
public class TestType {
    String value;
}
```

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Document(collection = "entity")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldNameConstants
public class Entity {

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "entity";

    @Id
    UUID id;

    @Builder.Default
    @Field(name = Fields.data)
    List<SomeOtherData> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Builder.Default
    TestType testType = new TestType("payload");
}
```

If written without converters, this code results in the following document:

```
{
    "id": someID,
    "data": {},
    "testType":{"value":"payload"}
}
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
{
    "id": someID,
    "data": {},
    "testType":"payload"
}
```

So I added two CustomConverters and added a bean to provide the mongoCustomConversions:

```
@WritingConverter
public class TestTypeStringConverter implements Converter<TestType, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(TestType source) {
        return source.getValue();
    }
}
```

```
@ReadingConverter
public class StringTestTypeConverter implements Converter<String, TestType> {
    @Override
    public TestType convert(@NonNull String source) {
        return new TestType(source);
    }
}
```

```
    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(List.of(
                new TestTypeStringConverter(),
                new StringTestTypeConverter()
        ));
    }
```

I use the mongoTemplate to write my changes to the database:

```
    private UpdateOneModel<Document> createUpdate(Entity newEntity) {
        var query = new Query().addCriteria(new Criteria(UNDERSCORE_ID).is(newEntity.getId()));
        var updateVehicle = new Update();
        var options = new UpdateOptions();
        options.upsert(true);
        updateVehicle.set(Entity.Fields.data, newEntity.getData());
        updateVehicle.set(Entity.Fields.testType, newEntity.getTestType());
        return new UpdateOneModel<>(query.getQueryObject(), updateVehicle.getUpdateObject(), options);
    }
```

```
private Mono<BulkWriteResult> execute(String collectionName, UpdateOneModel<Document> updateModelList) {
        return reactiveMongoTemplate.getCollection(collectionName)
                .flatMap(c -> Mono.from(c.bulkWrite(List.of(updateModelList))));
    }
```

But still my object gets written as without the converters.

Debugging confirmed that the mongoTemplate contains instances of my converters. Both are listed in the converters and in the writing- and readingPairs respectively.
I tried changing the datatypes but that also didnt change anything.
At that point I was out of ideas.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform an upsert, you are not utilizing Spring in the proper way. Instead, you are calling the `bulkWrite` method from the com.mongodb package. The converters that you have correctly defined, are a Spring concept present in SpringData Mongo.
I have used the same reactiveMongoTemplate but have employed the upsert method from SpringData Mongo and it works as expected.

I've made an example commit here: https://github.com/sbernardo/spring-issues-examples/tree/main/sof-questions-77612149

Regardless, you can still use your current approach with the bulk operation (you will find this code in my repo):

```java
var entity = new Entity(UUID.fromString("7f6a35fb-a449-4e31-b9c1-7592cc969d83"), new TestType("HelloValue"));

Update update = new Update();
update.set(Entity.Fields.testType, entity.getTestType());
update.set("field2", "otherFieldValue");

return reactiveMongoTemplate
        .bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, Entity.class)
        .upsert(Query.query(new Criteria(UNDERSCORE_ID).is(entity.getId())), update)
        .execute()
        .block()
        .toString();
```

I'm using spring-boot 3.2.0 and java 21.